# Getting data from edittext when switchbox is enabled in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

So, I got problem to get data from edittext when I cheked the switch box first I set the visibility of edittext is gone, and then when the switchbox is enabled/cheked, the edittext is shown, and then if edittext is not null or empty, it will be set the value of string `komentar` into what I put in the edittext, but I can't get the data from edittext if write the code like this :

```
String komentar="";
    Switch switch_komentar = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_komentar);
            edittext_komentar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_komentar);
            switch_komentar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    
                    if(isChecked){
                        edittext_komentar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        if(edittext_komentar.isShown() && !edittext_komentar.equals("")){
    
                            komentar=edittext_komentar.getText().toString();
                        }
    
                    }else {
                        edittext_komentar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But, when I try to enabled the switchbox 2 times, the data from the edittext I can get it, but when I'm change it again, the value is not changed, but when I'm try to enbaled for 2 times again, I can get it.

Comment: ```edittext_komentar.isShown()``` remove this line and then try it, because its very obvious that if your are setting the visibility as visible then you don't need to check for the visibility.

Comment: i've been remove that, but still get the same problem, i should enabled the switchbox for to times to  get the value of edittext

Answer (score 0):

this problem is solved, so im try to get the value of edittext not inside the shitchbox, im try to get the value outside the switchbox listener, thankyou